# how to update elements in a matrix with position identified in a list

Tags: matrix

I am new to mathematica. Could you pls help me on how to write this:

I have a $5\times 10$ matrix, for example,

```
ap = ConstantArray[0.001, {5, 10}]
```

I have the second matrix $1\times 10$, for example,

```
b = {0.001,0.005,0.009,0.01,0.03,0.05,0.082,0.1,0.5,1}
```

I have a nested `list z = {{1,3},{2,2},{5,7}}` for position.

I would like to have this result: In first matrix ap, for each row, for example row 1, if the element position is equal or larger than the second element in list Z in case the row number matches the first element (for example here it is 3), for every element in row 1 and after position 3 (include position 3), I would like to substitute elements in ap with elements from b, here would be substitute with `{0.009,0.01,0.03,0.05,0.082,0.1,0.5,1}`

Similarly for row 2 in matrix ap, I would like to substitute with elements in b starting position 2. So the final matrix is:

```
0.001,0.001,0.009,0.01,0.03,0.05,0.082,0.1,0.5,1

0.001,0.005,0.009,0.01,0.03,0.05,0.082,0.1,0.5,1

0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001
0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001

0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.082,0.1,0.5,1
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way:

```
ap = ConstantArray[0.001, {5, 10}];
b = {0.001, 0.005, 0.009, 0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.082, 0.1, 0.5, 1};
z = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {5, 7}};

f[ap_, {z1_, z2_}] := ReplacePart[ap, {z1, i_ /; i >= z2} :> b[[i]]]

Fold[f, ap, z]

(* {{0.001, 0.001, 0.009, 0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.082, 0.1, 0.5, 1},
    {0.001, 0.005, 0.009, 0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.082, 0.1, 0.5, 1},
    {0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001},
    {0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001},
    {0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.082, 0.1, 0.5, 1}} *)
```

Comment: A rather more elegant solution than mine, though maybe more difficult to understand for someone new to `Mathematica`.

Comment: This was what I was going to propose. +1.

Answer (score 3):

```
Table[Table[ap[[z[[i, 1]], j]] = b[[j]], {j, z[[i, 2]], 10}], {i, 3}];
ap
```

> {{0.001, 0.001, 0.009, 0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.082, 0.1, 0.5, 1},
>
> {0.001, 0.005, 0.009, 0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.082, 0.1, 0.5, 1},
>
> {0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001,
>   0.001},
>
> {0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001,
>   0.001},
>
> {0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.082, 0.1, 0.5, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Module[{m = #, r = #2, x = #3}, (m[[#, #2 ;;]] = r[[#2 ;;]]) & @@@x; m] &; 

f[ap, b, z]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]